# image view-- Is it possible to set the position of an UIImageView dynamicaly?

Tags: ipad, ios4, uiimageview, uiimage

Is it possible to set the position of an UIImageView  dynamicaly ? by moving Uislide bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use UISlide value change delegates and get the slide value,based on uislider value you can move the imageview by using `imageView.frame` property

Answer (score 1):

yes, just use frame property like this way

```
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f , 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f);
```

or

you can also use the setFrame function of imageView

```
[imageView setFrame: CGRectMake(0.0f , 0.0f, 32.0f, 32.0f)];
```

thats all, i think it will help you.

Comment: you can set a timer and increase it's time to timer.vlaue; And call the selector inside this you can modify your imageview Frame position

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just set UIImageVIew object frame. thats it.